# Как каждому новому подключившемуся пользователю назначить отдельный поток?

Tags: java, многопоточность, потоки-данных, telegram-bot, telegram

Стоит задача каждому новому клиенту отправившему информацию на сервер (клиенты telegram) выделить свой поток обработки данных, при повторных запросах от этого клиента все данные кидать в этот поток. Когда данные будут обработаны, а новые не придут, поток завершится. Если более детально, то клиенты отправляют серверу строку, которая в потоке(для каждого клиента он свой) проверяет есть ли идентичная строка в листе на сервере(со временем в лист будут подгружаться строки). И если до того как строка появится в листе придет еще одна строка от этого же клиента, то она тоже будет ждать идентичной в листе. Поток будет существовать пока все строки не обработаются,а новые не поступят.

Подскажите как это можно реализовать? Пытался создать фабрику потоков и добавлять в map пару id-поток, но в итоге получается, что все данные обрабатываются одним потоком, хотя в карту id добавляются.

Comment: Это можно, но не нужно. Иначе любой script-kiddie запустит 10К подключений и положит ваш сервер.

Comment: Можно ограничить круг клиентов, которые отправляют запросы боту.

Comment: мапа на id клиента и очередь заданий+Пул потоков?

Comment: взаимодействие асинхронное? клиент послал строчку и отключился? или ждет ответа?

Comment: Взаимодействие асинхронное

Comment: А можно узнать прикладной смысл этой задачи?

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю следующее решение. Сделать потоки без состояния, тогда можно сразу же создать пул с заданным размером. Это будет и безопаснее и удобнее при реализации. Тогда, при получении очередной порции данных из сокета, создавать задачу, и передавать ее на выполнение потокам из пула.

Сервер тогда будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
private static class SocketServerExample {
    private final Selector selector;
    private final InetSocketAddress listenAddress;
    private final ExecutorService executors;

    private SocketServerExample(String address, 
                                int port, 
                                int countOfThreads) throws IOException {

        this.listenAddress = new InetSocketAddress(address, port);
        this.selector = Selector.open();
        this.executors = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(countOfThreads);
    }

    private void start() throws IOException {
        ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        serverChannel.socket().bind(listenAddress);
        serverChannel.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            this.selector.select();

            Iterator keys = this.selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) keys.next();

                keys.remove();

                if (!key.isValid())
                    continue;

                if (key.isAcceptable())
                    accept(key);
                else if (key.isReadable())
                    executors.execute(new RequestHandler(key));
            }
        }
    }

    private void accept(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
        ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
        SocketChannel channel = serverChannel.accept();
        channel.configureBlocking(false);
        channel.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    }
}
```

Обработчик данных будет таким:

```
private static class RequestHandler implements Runnable {
    private final SelectionKey selectionKey;

    private RequestHandler(SelectionKey selectionKey) {
        this.selectionKey = selectionKey;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) selectionKey.channel();
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
            int numRead = channel.read(buffer);

            if (numRead == -1) {
                channel.close();
                selectionKey.cancel();
                return;
            }
            String data = new String(buffer.array());
            if(data.trim().isEmpty())
                return;

            String content = " >> " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " >> " + data;
            System.out.println(content);
            buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(content.getBytes());
            channel.write(buffer);

        } catch (Exception e) {
           // throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
 }
```

А чтобы запустить сервер, нужно написать вот так:

```
final String address = "localhost";
final int port = 9999;

new SocketServerExample(address, port, 10).start();
```